# CSS from a Vue Single File Component overrides some CSS from buefy/bulma and some not

Tags: css, vue.js, bulma

I hope someone can give me a hint, how to investigate this issue.

In a Vue project, buefy is included from `main.js` like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue' 
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import './style.scss'
Vue.use(Buefy)

import Client from './client.vue' 

let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(Client) 
})
```

, where `style.css` imports buefy/bulma styles:

```
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all";
[...]
@import "~bulma";
@import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy";
```

Buefy/Bulma css should be overriden by styles defined in single file vue components like:

```
<style lang="scss">
.logLine{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 1em; 
}
</style>
```

The strange observation is, that while `padding` overrides bulma styles (as expected), `margin` is overridden by bulma styles:

[screenshot from firefox css inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct0fx.png)

It shows, that while styles from `bulma/sass/base/minireset.sass` get overridden by `.logLine` style definitions from the single file component. But `.logLine` style definitions get overridden by `bulma/sass/elements/content.sass`.

I expect the styles from `.logLine` to override all Buefy/Bulma styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often happens, when formulating the question, details catch your attention that guide you to the answer:

The style from bulma that was overriding my styles from the single file component was using the css pseudo class `:last-child`

```css
.content p:not(:last-child), [...] {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

I think this `:last-child` makes firefox grant this style rule precedence.

I "solved" the problem by adding `.content .logLine:not(:last-child)` to the selectors in the single file component.

```css
.content .logLine:not(:last-child), 
.logLine, {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Now it does not get overridden anymore.

Comment: Note that I had to use ```.content .logLine:not(:last-child)```. Just ```.logLine:not(:last-child)``` would have no effect. Can some CSS master explain the order of precedence here?